# How to mark as read e-mails from a certain person in mail app

Tags: macos, mail.app

There is e-mail group that I'm a part of. I don't want to quit the group, because occasionally something interesting gets posted. However, I get a large volume of e-mails that are not interesting. Is there a way to mark these e-mails as read in mail app automatically? Just to be clear, I want to keep everything else unread unless I read them. I just want the e-mails from this specific group to be marked as read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "Rules" feature of Mail in Yosemite, you can make it so emails from a certain address are automatically marked as read by following these steps:

1. Open Preferences (CMD + , or Preferences in the Mail Menu)
2. Navigate to the Rules Tab (furthest to the right)
3. "Add Rule"
4. Condition: "From" "is equal to" "(email goes here)"
5. Action: "Mark as Read"

Comment: Since it's an email group, there is a likelihood that the emails are not all from the same person. But the answer does still apply, in that a rule can be crafted with some piece of information common to all of the messages (such as a subject line prefix, word[s] in the message, etc).

Comment: @tubedogg there was a certain word in brackets in the subject which I could use. Thanks :)